# How to find all words that ends with colon (:) using regex

Tags: python, regex, typescript, regex-group

I am new to regex, I have the following expressions, I want to find the word or consecutive words ending with colon(:) using regular expression.

```
Incarcerate: imprison or confine, Strike down: if someone is struck down, especially by an illness, they are killed or severely harmed by it, Accost: approach and address.
```

The output should be like this `Incarcerate:, Strike down:, Accost:` . I have written the following regex, but it captures the following.

My regex -> `(\w+):+`

It captures the words like `Incarcerate:, Accost:`, it does not capture `Strike down:`
Please help me.

I want to do it in both typescript and python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can optionally repeat a space and 1+ word chars. Note that the words are in group 1, and the `:` is outside of the group.

```
(\w+(?: \w+)*):
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3UcY7D/1)

To include the `:` in the match:

```
\w+(?: \w+)*:
```

The pattern matches

- `\w+` Match 1 or more word characters
- `(?: \w+)*` Repeat 0+ times matching a space and 1+ word characters
- `:` Match a single `:`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Y1xuLy/1)

Example in Python

```
import re
s = "Incarcerate: imprison or confine, Strike down: if someone is struck down, especially by an illness, they are killed or severely harmed by it, Accost: approach and address."
pattern = r"\w+(?: \w+)*:"
 
print(re.findall(pattern, s))
```

Output

```
['Incarcerate:', 'Strike down:', 'Accost:']
```

Comment: @dawg I already removed it, always a bad idea to copy paste without checking

Comment: Sir, excellent, it worked. Sir, could you help me to understand this part `(?: \w+)`

Comment: @Deba I have added an explanation about the pattern.